# At what stage is error thrown?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

Compilation generally occur in several stages:lexical analysis, syntax analysis, etc. Say, in C language, I wrote

```
a=24;
```

without declaring `a` as `int`. Now, at what stage of compilation an error is detected? At syntax analysis stage? If that is the case, then what does lexical analyzer do? Just tokenizing the source code?

Comment: depends on the language, I suggest you narrow down your question only on C.

Comment: I'd say it's syntax analysis

Comment: The stages you are talking about may be a simplified picture.

Comment: Lexical analyzer find only tokens in source code and give them to syntax analyzer witch check it with language grammar , mb this will help you http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf . Or try to read "Dragon book"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If talking about a general form of compiler,it is obvious that **the error will occur at the syntax analysis phase when the parser will look for the symbol searching in symbol table entries** ,*and the subsequent phases - only if processed further after recovering from error*.

[The dragon book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811)  also clearly tells that. It is mentioned in the page where the types of error are mentioned. The topic to be studied thoroughly to understand this issue is given in ***4.1.3 - Syntax Error Handling*** .

```
a = 24;   // without declaring a as an int type variable.
```

Here, the work of lexical phase is simply to access characters and form tokens and subsequently pass them to the further phases,i.e., to the parse in the syntax analysis phase,etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.So,If I write "int a = 24",lexical analyzer tokenizes this into "int","a","=","24".whenever it sees int,it adds the next token(in this case-a) to the symbol table.when next time "a" comes syntax analyzer sees it in symbol table and everything goes normal.am I right?

Comment: @anil- Yeah,all entries are checked in the symbol table before insertion to avoid duplication. Hence, we generally use HashTable as the efficient data structure to implement Symbol Table so that the lookup complexity is O(k) or O(1),whatever you think best between the two.

Comment: I don't think that's obvious. I'd say, in general, that the error would occur in *semantic* analysis, not *syntactic* --- because `a = 24;` is a perfectly valid statement (simplified grammar: `decl_expr := lvalue '=' rvalue ';'`). Only in semantic analysis does it figure out that `a` had not been declared. However, when talking *specifically* about C, the lines are usually somewhat blurred, and you could argue that it happens in either (or maybe both).

Comment: @TimČas- No SIR,a will be searched in the symbol table first so that if the entry exists then it won't be inserted. If not, then a should have been inserted in the symbol table in the lexical analysis phase, thereby resulting in error. I am quoting a line from the dragon book SIR -

Comment: @TimČas-`he precision of parsing methods allows syntactic errors to be detected very
efficiently. Several parsing methods, such as the LL and LR methods, detect4. 1. INTRODUCTION
195
an error as soon as possible; that is, when the stream of tokens from the lexical
analyzer cannot be parsed further according to the grammar for the language.
More precisely, they have the viable-prefix property, meaning that they detect
that an error has occurred as soon as they see a prefix of the input that cannot
be completed to form a string in the language`

Comment: @TimČas-`nother reason for emphasizing error recovery during parsing is that many
errors appear syntactic, whatever their cause, and are exposed when parsing
cannot continue. A few semantic errors, such as type mismatches, can also be
detected efficiently; however, accurate detection of semantic and logical errors
at compile time is in general a difficult task.` I hope this clears the doubt SIR.

Comment: @shekharsuman It makes sense to understand that syntax analyzer detects error.But in the section 4.1.3 in dragon book,it says MISSPELLINGS OF IDENTIDIERS is a lexical error.there error is because of the fact that particulat token is not in the symbol table.the question I posted is also the same case nah..

Comment: @anil- The question is not the same,but,the same concept would be applied here because you only tell how will parser do justice with this line `a=24` without knowing the whereabouts about `a`! It's just a matter of facts how you relate things. BTW, you are most welcome to other standard books and online links about examples of syntax errors in compiler-design.

Comment: @TimČas- Also, I forgot to mention that I've already mentioned *the error will occur at the syntax analysis phase when the parser will look for the symbol searching in symbol table entries*,**and the subsequent phases - only if processed further after recovering from error.**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your compiler, but in general this would be in the parsing stage (syntax analysis) and not the lexical stage (tokenizing). Most C compilers will be written using a lex/yacc variant, which makes the above assumption more plausible. If you want to know the details, dive into [the dragon book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools), a great resource.

If I were to write the compiler, I'd have the lexical analyzer spit out tokens (in this case: a, =, 24 and finally ;). The parser would maintain a symbol table and upon seeing the symbol a it would check whether the symbol was in the table; if not (as in your example) it would signal an error.